# Why can I only get a usable resolution in the Live CD environment?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display, display-resolution, nomodeset

I am trying to install Ubuntu(or any distro that works, really) on an old Compaq CQ5500F with integrated Nvidia Geforce 6150se Nforce 430 GPU.

It was using Windows 7 and looked fine, but was frustratingly slow.

The live distros(ubuntu, lubuntu, xubuntu, bodhi...) require "nomodeset" parameter to use the display, and it gives a 1024x768 usable picture. Puppy linux gives even higher resolutions but seems unstable. In the live distro, xrandr lists multiple resolutions.

After installing, the resolution will be 640x480 with "nomodeset" and, without it, the monitor gives "out-of-signal" error. Xrandr lists only that resolution and so do the GUIs to change the display settings.

Installing the proprietary nvidia-304 drivers results in the login screen briefly appearing, then glitching out, and then "out-of-signal". The command line terminals can be accessed, "lshw -c video" says the driver is nvidia. Xrandr can't open the display(because proprietary drivers?). Purging/removing *nvidia allows the computer to boot back into 640x480.

I have installed drivers with ubuntu-drivers, install nvidia-304, and downloading the current and recommended older 304.117 drivers from nvidia website. I've tried boot-repair, every combination of nomodeset, nouveau.noaccel=1 and acpi=off in the kernel boot options, uncommenting grub resolution, different display managers. I've tried Ubuntu 14, 15 and 17 I believe and Debian gives the same issues.

A fix or distro recommendation would be nice but, above all, I would love to know why the Live CD can, without fail, deliver a clean 1024x768 picture that ceases to be available after installation.

Also, Puppy Linux Tahr seems to work okay but I would like multi-user support and a little more stability(I get kernel panics and freezes).

Edit: Antix 16 32 bit Linux distribution works with nomodeset. If you do install this, note that there are some political bookmarks included in the default browser.

Edit: Mint 13 works, after installing had to manually add nomodeset in /etc/default/grub and run grub-update from live cd. I will try later versions and report back.

Comment: A similar(?) old nvidia chip,  C68 [GeForce 7050 PV / nForce 630a], works for me with Lubuntu (installed from the Lubuntu 16.04.1 LTS i386 iso file). It works both with and without an nvidia proprietary driver. Maybe you should try with console mode (to avoid getting locked into 640x480 resolution), See this link, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#A.2Fetc.2Fdefault.2Fgrub; Try to "**uncomment** (remove the # character) 10. **#GRUB_TERMINAL=console**" from `/etc/default/grub` and run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: @sudodus Thanks, but not luck. I did find a distribution that works okay, though(Antix).

Comment: I'm glad that you found a linux distro, that works in your computer with that old nvidia chip. *Thanks for sharing your solution*. It can be help other users :-)